# How to change mesh using driver like cgcookie cookieFlexRig?

Tags: modeling, drivers

how I can change mesh into another mesh using driver.
I found in cookieFlexRig it easy to change clothing model, hair, shoes.
How to do this?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flex rig doesn't change the mesh, every hair mesh is in place at all times, the visibility is changed by using a mask modifier.

For each hair object, add a mask modifier, then add a driver for the invert option and set the driver calculation so that when a certain value is set the invert is the right way for each object.

[image: mask modifier]

[image: example]

A [driver](https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/drivers.html) is a python expression that determines the value of the property being driven. In the case of controlling the mask modifier, the result should be a True or False value that inverts the mask effect. Drivers can be edited in the [driver context of the graph editor](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html#header-controls).

The flexrig uses each number to "view" a different mesh object, the easy way to determine which is active is to test if a custom property is equal to the chosen number for each item. For example `choice == 1` will be True when the custom property is set to 1. A [custom property](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/custom_properties.html) can be added to an object in the custom properties panel which is found in the [object properties](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/properties_editor.html).

The driver panel looks a little different in 2.78 but it isn't hard to find the same settings - you choose single property and select the object that has the controlling property then enter the property name as if it was a dictionary key in python `["good"]` into the path property, then you use the driver variable name in the scripted expression `choice == 1`

[image: driver settings]

[image]

Comment: thanks, now I can hide and unhide the mesh, but I not understand for the driver part, could you share that blend file?